# Entity Framework 5 disable object mocking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

My apologies in advance that I am not an EF export.
My team have inherited a MVC3 project using EF5 on .NET 4.0. There are a lot of mock objects automatically generated by TT(?) template.  We have multiple developers working on the project and constantly causing conflicting errors on the mock objects and we wonder if it is possible to tweak EDMX NOT to generate the mock objects?  We tried to delete the test files but they seem to get generated every time we updates the EDMX.
We know that it's a good practice to automate the unit testing but we are running out of time and the budget would not allow us to spend too much time automating unit tests.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to fully understand what you mean, but it sounds like you have templates that automatically build when you compile. If so, you can turn turn that off by editing your project file. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx#Regenerating

Comment: By default EDMX does not generate any mock objects. The classes generated from EDMX is ObjectContext and entity definitions. Without these you won't be able to connect to database. Either you are treating classes generated by EF as mocks or you are using some customizations in which case I don't think anyone can tell what's going on in your project if you don't show it. If this is TT just try removing `.tt` files. Hopefully you are using source control and you can do whatever you want to your project and revert changes if things don't work.

Comment: Thanks.It shows how much I know about EDMX.  I deleted the files <filename>Mock.cs (or <filename>Moc.objectset.cs) but they keep coming  back every where I have made changes to the EDMX.  I am researching on how this happens.